# Distributed TensorFlow hangs during CreateSession

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I am new to distributed TensorFlow. Right now I am just trying to get some existing examples to work so I can learn how to do it right.

I am following the instruction here to train the inception network on one Linux machine with one worker and one PS. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception#how-to-train-from-scratch-in-a-distributed-setting

The program hangs during CreateSession with the message: 
CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0

This my command to start a worker:

```
./bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
    --batch_size=32 \
    --data_dir=/datasets/BigLearning/jinlianw/imagenet_tfrecords/ \
    --job_name='worker' \
    --task_id=0 \
    --ps_hosts='localhost:2222' \
    --worker_hosts='localhost:2223'
```

This is my command to start a PS:

```
./bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
    --job_name='ps' \
    --task_id=0 \
    --ps_hosts='localhost:2222' \
    --worker_hosts='localhost:2223'
```

And the PS process hangs after printing:

> 2018-06-29 21:40:43.097361: I
>   tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:332]
>   Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222

Is the inception model still a valid example for distributed TensorFlow or did I do something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this could be due to multiple reasons. See my issue on TF: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41101    I mentioned couple of environnement variable to set to get more logs from grpc. Glad you found a solution. How did you figured it out ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Turns out it's due to GRPC. My cluster machines have an environment variable http_proxy set. Unset this variable solves the problem.